# UnicodeDecodeError even when importing simple txt file in Python

Tags: python, io

I would like to import even a simple text file into Python. For example, here's the contents of `example.txt`:

```
hello
my
friend
```

Very simple. However, when I try to import the file and read it:

```
f = open('example.txt')
f.read()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    f.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What's the source of this problem? Clearly there are not any non-ascii characters in the file.

I've tried this in IDLE, terminal (Mac OSX) and Rodeo and get similar issues in all.

I'm very new to Python and am concerned I may have screwed up something in installation. I've downloaded various versions over the years, straight from Python, Anaconda, macports, etc. and I'm wondering if the various sources are not playing nicely...

Python 3.5.1 on OSX 10.11.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your file is saved with the encoding `UTF-8 with BOM` (Byte order mark). Try to save you file explicit as `UTF-8` (without BOM). While the BOM is not included in the `ASCII` codec, it causes an `UnicodeError`.

Hope this helps!